# How do I remove unused CSS/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm making a schoolproject, a web page. I got a bootstrap example, which had loads of code in it, but most of it is just random unused css/jQuery. And there is loads of duplicates. It's hard to find anything to be honest.

Is there a way to remove unused css/jQuery from the web page automatically? More interested in jQuery removal.

Comment: You should download custom bootstrap version where you can select only those library which you need. Plus use javasciprt minifier to remove duplicate or long code.

Comment: Which minifier would you recommend?

Comment: Download boostrap SCSS instead and you can comment out particular partial scss files `@import _nameOfPartial.scss` that you're not needing

Answer (score 4):

To remove unused css code, you have multiple options:

1. Use the Bootstrap v3 [customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)
2. Compile the .scss/.less components you need ([v4](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4-dev/scss) or [v3](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v3-dev/less))
3. Use [uncss](https://github.com/giakki/uncss) (check [using uncss with Bootstrap](https://github.com/giakki/uncss/wiki/Using-uncss-with-Bootstrap))

To remove unused js code, you also have multiple options:

1. Google's [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) (with `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` enabled)
2. [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) (with `dead_code` option)
3. [Dead Javascript Eliminator](https://github.com/bramsey/Dead-Javascript-Eliminator)

Comment: yea, i have no clue, how to use those node etc stuff. im not gonna lie.

Comment: @part you dont need to know how to work with node. you can do:

- For css: bootstrap costumizer
- For js: uglify

To use uglify, you only need to:

- install node (latest version, npm is included)
- run this on the command line: `npm install uglify-js -g`
- run this on the command line: `uglifyjs -c 'dead_code' -- your_file.js`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your unused css using in a gulp environment using [gulp-purgecss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-purgecss).

For more explaination, have a look on this [DEMO](https://github.com/Mohamed-Talaat333/gulp-boilerplate) and read it's docs.